# Generating random number in a sequence using VBscript

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm new to vbscript.

I've got this so far

```
Function random_number_generator (lowerLim, upperLim)
    Randomize
    randNumber = Int(((upperLim-lowerLim+1)* Rnd())+ lowerLim)
    random_number_generator = randNumber
End Function
```

But how do I make it to have a sequence for generating let's say 9 digit social security number?

for example if the first social security is 200030886 next would be 200030887 and so on.

Comment: A 9-digit number is just any number between 0 and 999999999, so all you need to do is adjust your upper and lower limits accordingly.

Comment: Can you post what you need the output to look like. Please include a couple of examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have a random element to your question. I seems like you just want a counter?

```
Dim start, ends
start = 200030886
ends = 200040000

for k = start to ends
    MsgBox k
next
```

If you need a random number formatted like the numbers above, you can try this.

```
MsgBox random_number_generator(1, 10000)

Function random_number_generator (lowerLim, upperLim)
    Randomize
    randNumber = Int(((upperLim-lowerLim+1)* Rnd())+ lowerLim)
    random_number_generator = "2" & RIGHT("000000000" & randNumber, 8)
End Function
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim RandNumber

RandNumber = RandomNumber(1,10000)

Print RandNumber
```

Comment: There is no RandomNumber function in VBScript.